# Entering data in entry widget in focus using a keypad of buttons

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

There are multiple entry widgets in my tkinter gui. So I want to use a single function to enter data in the entry widget currently in focus with the help of a keypad of buttons. How can I do it?

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Please include a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and give a meaningful name 9(like screenshot) to your image.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `root.focus_get()` to get the current focused widget, derive StringVar/IntVar and update them properly, or just use `entry.insert('end','0')` for example.